# Conserved charges for complex scalar fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

I have been studying complex scalar fields, and in Peskin and Schroeder, *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*, (chapter 2, problem 2, part d— on page 34) they ask you to compute the conserved charges for two equally massive complex scalar fields. So far I understand that the corresponding Lagrangian is invariant under $U(2)$ (which gives four separate conserved charges). But in a note, it says there are actually six. I don't see where the other two could come from. Is it related to the Lagrangian being invariant under a bigger symmetry group that I didn't notice?

Comment: Where are you getting six charges?  My copy not only specifies that there should be four charges, it states exactly what they are.

Comment: At the bottom of the page it says: ''With some additional work you can show that there are actually six conserved charges in the case of two complex fields, and $n(2n-1 )$ in the case of $n$ fields, corresponding to the generators of the rotation group in four and $2 n$ dimensions, respectively. The extra symmetries often do not survive when nonlinear interactions of the fields are included.''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two complex scalar fields $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ can be rewritten as four real fields, in terms of their real and imaginary parts,
$$\Phi=\sqrt{2}\left[\begin{array}{c}
\Re\{\phi_{1}\} \\
\Im\{\phi_{1}\} \\
\Re\{\phi_{2}\} \\
\Im\{\phi_{2}\}
\end{array}\right].$$
For the free theory, the Lagrange density is actually equal to
$${\cal L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial^{\mu}\Phi_{i}\partial_{\mu}\Phi_{i}-\frac{m^{2}}{2}\Phi_{i}\Phi_{i},$$
with the $i=1,\ldots,4$ summed over. This is just the sum of four Lagrange densities for four independent real fields $\Phi_{i}$.  This is clearly invariant under real $SO(4)$ rotations, of which there are six.

However, these symmetries do not survive under the natural interactions for complex (i.e. charged) scalar fields, such as the current coupling term $\left[\phi_{j}^{*}(\partial^{\mu}\phi_{j})-(\partial^{\mu}\phi_{j}^{*})\phi_{j}\right]A_{\mu}$, (now summed over $j=1,2$).

(My copy of the book—a relatively early printing—does not have the footnote mentioned in the question.  However, the relationship between four real fields and two complex fields is discussed a bit further in problem 4.3.)